# Flask not including/utilising Bootstrap

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, flask, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble getting Bootstrap to do anything via Flask.

Here's a quick test example which should work, however it doesn't seem to be applying the styling (even though bootstrap is available via their CDN in the sources tab).

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__)


    Bootstrap(app)
    @app.route('/test')
    def test():
        return render_template('test.html')
```

test.html

```
    {% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
    {% endblock %}
```

Result:

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deJ5V.png)

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1OKR.png)

Both Flask and flask-bootstrap are the latest version from pip.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

It seems flask-bootstrap only uses Bootstrap3, whereas I was trying to use components introduced in Bootstrap4.

Updated base.html (in flask-bootstrap) to utilize the latest Bootstrap4 cdns.